# Add html formatting to body of email - Suitescript

Tags: javascript, html, email, netsuite, suitescript

I have written a script to send an email alert if products of a certain type are missing from a quote.

Very straightforward, very simple.

All I want to do now is include in the email some basic info like sales rep and division.

I know I can do the +repName etc like below.

However when I do this there are no spaces and everything is on one line.
So I want to do some basic formatting, a couple of line breaks, a field label.

But if I put repName or itemDivision in between the quotes then they appear as just the text, not the variable values.

How do I insert the variables into the body of an email so I can format them? I assume I have to enclose them in tags of some kind?

Cannot find the information anywhere.

Not interested in any fancy complex rendering techniques or writing a million lines of code. The information is already there, I just want to include in a slightly more visually friendly way.

Thank you

```
log.debug({
    title: 'Line Item Division',
    details: itemDivision
});

if (itemDivision !== 'Media') {

    email.send({
        author: ** ** ,
        recipients: 'an email address',
        subject: 'Quote Without Media',
        body: "A Test" + itemDivision + repName

    });
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried including HTML tags within the body string?

Comment: Hi Kiran. Yes, for example I can use <br /> in the body no problem and it does a line break. But the variables are still outside of the body so I cannot separate them by line or add another line break between them. For example "A Test < /br>" +itemDivision < /br> + repName - throws a syntax error.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `"A Test <br>" + itemDivision + "<br>" + repName`. The tags need to be within a string. Alternatively, you could use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Perfection. Thank you @Sean - I'd tried that earlier but didn't realised I needed another + in order to add more quote encapsulated elements. Thank you again, the devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Sean in the comments.

After the initial section in quotes " " if you want to add more HTML tags then you need to use a + before the new section So "Some text" +variable +"Some more HTML" +variable etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the pitfalls of concatenating a bunch of strings by using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  Note the use of backticks instead of quotes to indicate it's a template literal.

```
body: `
<div>${repName} claims that ${itemDivision} is the best division</div>
<div>for more info <a href='someurl?rep=${repName}&division=${itemDivision}'>click here</a></div>
`
```